# In Perl, How do I replace UTF8 characters, such as \x91, \x{2018}, \x{2013}, \x{2014} with simple ASCII chars?

Tags: perl, encoding, character-encoding, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I'm working with various articles and the problem I'm having is that various authors use various characters for punctuation characters.

For example, several documents that I'm currently work with have characters such as:

```
\x91
\x92
\x{2018}
\x{2019}
```

And all these characters represent a simple quote `'`.

What I want to do is simplify the articles so they all had the same formatting style.

Does anyone know a module, or a method, of converting these character and similar ones (like double quotes, dashes, etc) to simple ASCII characters?

I'm currently doing things like:

```
sub fix_chars_in_document {
    my $document = shift;
    $document =~ s/\xa0/ /g;
    $document =~ s/\x91/'/g;
    $document =~ s/\x92/'/g;
    $document =~ s/\x93/"/g;
    $document =~ s/\x94/"/g;
    $document =~ s/\x97/-/g;
    $document =~ s/\xab/"/g;
    $document =~ s/\xa9//g;
    $document =~ s/\xae//g;
    $document =~ s/\x{2018}/'/g;
    $document =~ s/\x{2019}/'/g;
    $document =~ s/\x{201C}/"/g;
    $document =~ s/\x{201D}/"/g;
    $document =~ s/\x{2022}//g;
    $document =~ s/\x{2013}/-/g;
    $document =~ s/\x{2014}/-/g;
    $document =~ s/\x{2122}//g; 
    return $document ;
}
```

But this is very hard as I've to manually find the characters and replace them.

Comment: Perhaps look at Text::Unidecode on CPAN.

Comment: @DaveCross I just tried it but it affects all characters, not just dashes, dots, quotes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, your solution would benefit from a hash.

```
my %asciify = (
   chr(0x00A0) => ' ',
   chr(0x0091) => "'",
   chr(0x0092) => "'",
   chr(0x0093) => '"',
   chr(0x0094) => '"',
   chr(0x0097) => '-',
   chr(0x00AB) => '"',
   chr(0x00A9) => '/',
   chr(0x00AE) => '/',
   chr(0x2018) => "'",
   chr(0x2019) => "'",
   chr(0x201C) => '"',
   chr(0x201D) => '"',
   chr(0x2022) => '/',
   chr(0x2013) => '-',
   chr(0x2014) => '-',
   chr(0x2122) => '/',
);

my $pat = join '', map quotemeta, keys %asciify;
my $re = qr/[$pat]/;

sub fix_chars {
    my ($s) = @_;
    $s =~ s/($re)/$asciifi{$1}/g;
    return $s;
}
```

That said, you want [Text::Unidecode](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aUnidecode).

---

Just punctuation characters:

```
use Text::Unidecode qw( unidecode );
s/(\p{Punct}+)/ unidecode($1) /eg;
```

Comment: Of course, that assumes you really are confined to ASCII. I hope you're not just taking the "throwing out the baby with the bath water" approach to bug fixing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried Text::Unidecode but it also turns characters like `a'` (a with thing on top) to simple `a`, etc. I only need to convert dashes and quotes and other simple punctuation characters to ascii.